# My index view doesnt exist on rake routes

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, routes

I understand sorta why my `reviser` index page isn't showing up, but I don't know how to go about it. In my rake routes there is no reviser#index even though I made a `def index` on my controller. I have a `has_one` relation between a `user` and `reviser`, as a `user` can apply to become a `reviser`. This is the url to show a specific reviser `http://localhost:3000/users/15/reviser` however I also want there to be a way to see your profile as if you are the current user.  That's why I set up an index. So I want a url that shows only my current user as a reviser based off my index ex. `http://localhost:3000/users/reviser` or `http://localhost:3000/reviser` how might I be able to make my index page show up as current user page.  To sum it up: my **ReviserController** index isn't showing up in routes. Want url to be http://localhost:3000/reviser for `current_user`. Thank you!

**ReviserController:**

```rails
class RevisersController < ApplicationController

before_action :set_reviser, only: [:show, :edit, :update]
before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:show]

  def index
    @reviser = current_user.reviser
  end

  def show

  end

  def new
    @reviser = current_user.build_reviser(params[:reviser])
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  end

  def create
    @reviser = current_user.reviser.build(reviser_params)

    if @reviser.save
      redirect_to @reviser,notice: "saved...."
    else 
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    set_reviser
  end

  def update
    set_reviser
    if @reviser.update(reviser_params)
      redirect_to @reviser,notice: "updated.."
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

private 
def set_reviser
  @reviser = current_user.reviser
end

  def reviser_params
    params.require(:reviser).permit(:description, :average_start, :average_end, :max_pages, :price_per, :active)
end
end
```

index.html

```html
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-3">
  <ul class="sidebar-list">
   <li class="sidebar-item"><%= link_to "Your Reviser Profile", reviser_path, class: "sidebar-list active" %></li>
   <li class="sidebar-item"><%= link_to "Your Essays", reviser_path, class: "sidebar-list active" %></li>
  </ul>
 </div> 
 <div class="col-md-9">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
   <div class="panel-heading">
    Reviser
   </div>
   <div class="panel-body">
   <% @reviser.each do |reviser| %>
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-2">
      <%= link_to image_tag(current_user.avatar.url(:medium), class:'img-responsive'), user_path(user) %>
      
     </div>
    </div>
   <% end %>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>  
</div>
```

**routes.rb:**

```
resources :users, only: [:index, :show] do 
    resource :reviser
 end
```

**Rake routes:** (index for reviser doesn't show up!!!)

1. user_reviser POST     /users/:user_id/reviser(.:format)                  revisers#create
2. new_user_reviser GET      /users/:user_id/reviser/new(.:format)              revisers#new
3. edit_user_reviser GET      /users/:user_id/reviser/edit(.:format)             revisers#edit
4. GET      /users/:user_id/reviser(.:format)                  revisers#show
5. PATCH    /users/:user_id/reviser(.:format)                  revisers#update
6. PUT      /users/:user_id/reviser(.:format)                  revisers#update
7. DELETE   /users/:user_id/reviser(.:format)                  revisers#destroy
8. users GET      /users(.:format)                                   users#index
9. user GET      /users/:id(.:format)                               users#show

Comment: `resources :revisers` - if you specify this, you will get to see `index` route

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see [in the rails route guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources) singular resource like the one you are using does not add an index method.

You should modify your routes.rb file to

```
resources :users, only: [:index, :show] do 
    resources :revisers
end
```

Comment: would this mean my has one relationship still works??

Comment: Of course, it is just the relation between models, whereas it looks like you want to show the reviser page using the index action (strange, but ok if this is the way you want you webapp to behave)

Comment: well the reason is because then the reviser can see links on the side to his own things, and the show will be for other users with different links on the side. Example in index ill have edit reviser page. for show ill have view more revisers.

Comment: I understand, but index actions are used to show more than a object in table layout. If you are using has_one, you will always have just one reviser linked to the user. So you could use the show action and show the available actions based on the session id

Comment: so youre saying I could still show my links only for the current user and have other users see only what i want them to see? only using the show? Would this be more efficient?  And where might I find out how to do that?  O I could make an if current_user? then have the html and else for the other

Comment: It would definitley be clearer, if you want just a small hint on how to do that check it out [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-session-cookies.htm)

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have it listed as a singular resource

from  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources

```
2.5 Singular Resources
Sometimes, you have a resource that clients always look up without referencing an ID.
For example, you would like /profile to always show the profile of the currently logged in user. 
 In this case, you can use a singular resource to map /profile (rather than /profile/:id) to the show action:
```

and it only creates the 6 actions that you see listed..

as there is only 1 resource, no sense showing an index.  just move your logic into the `show` action

```
def show
    @reviser = current_user.reviser
end
```

and rename `index.html.erb` to `show.html.erb`

Comment: I see what you're saying but I would also like other users to be able to view the revisers info! so i would just put that in show for the other users who want to check it out!?

Comment: as stated in accepted answer,  this just shows the revisor for the currently selected user.  when you `GET /users/:user_id/reviser `, you would show the revisor for user with a given user_id.  If you wanted to show all revisers in the system you would normally do that in the index, (and not have it nested under the user).

Comment: So other users wouldnt be able to see my show then.. Is there a way they could see the reviser profile still, and my user still able to see his?

Comment: you can easily move your revisers to not be nested under users.  And have it as stand alone resources. so you could browse / show revisers, and the your user#show would just have a link to reviser_path(user.reviser)  or similar .